# Azure IoTHub Device does not receive every Twin changes

Tags: .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to receive all twin desired changes in a function. I created 100 device client for 100 Iot Hub devices. I added callback function for each of them to catch updated desired twin properties.
If I want to update desired properties of 10 devices, the callback function should be run 10 times but it runs sometimes never, sometimes 3, sometimes 5, etc... (but all devices twins are updated)

Why the callback function doesn't receive all twin updates?

Using:

- Microsoft.Azure.Devices 1.20.1
- Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.25.0

Server code:

```
public async Task AddCallBackToTwins(DesiredPropertyUpdateCallback desiredPropertyUpdateCallback)
{
    var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("select * from devices");
    foreach (var t in await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync())
    {
        //.. create iot hub device connection string
        var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        await deviceClient.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync(DesiredPropertyUpdateCallback, null);
    }
}

static int count = 1;
public async Task DesiredPropertyUpdateCallback(TwinCollection desiredProperties, object userContext)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Callback:"+ count++);
}
```

Client Code: It updates twin desired property of 10 devices

```
// get 10 device ids
// create iot hub service connection string
var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
foreach (var deviceId in deviceIds)
{
    var twin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);
    twin.Properties.Desired["Pressure"] = "10.2";
    await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Callback:1
Callback:2
Callback:3
Callback:4
Callback:5
Callback:6
Callback:7
Callback:8
Callback:9
Callback:10
```

Example Output

```
Callback:1
Callback:2
Callback:3
```

Comment: you should rewrite your code for device side, either where each *deviceclient* will run in the separate task or create the console program for configurable device and then launch program for each device. This is a threading issue, not the Azure IoT Hub.

Comment: What connectionstring are you using in the DeviceClient, server side?  It really does not feel good that you are creating multiple device clients in the cloud, unless if you are building a cloud gateway.  In that case, you should indeed follow the advise of @RomanKiss and make sure you spin up a different thread (or even actors/services) for every device

Comment: connectionstring is "HostName={hubUrl};DeviceId={deviceId};SharedAccessKey={device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey}". I need to simulate 1k to 30k devices, communicate between iothub and devices. I guess creaing 30k thread is meaningless(30k process is implossible).  Also this threads/process need to live forever because I can send from any device to iothub anytime. Therefore I'm trying to make whole job in one process and creating device clients from there. @RomanKiss and SamVanhoutte

Comment: @Zupermen what do you mean by "all devices twins are updated"? Their reported properties all get the desired value? Thanks

Comment: @asergaz Let say we updated 5 devices, (their names: Id1,Id2,Id3,Id3,Id5) the call back function could run for Id1,Id2,Id3. (Not for Id4 and Id5) However, if I check the twin properties of all devices in the Azure portal, the properties of all devices (Id1,Id2,Id3,Id3,Id5) appear updated.

Comment: Are you adding different desired property values for the different devices? Just to make sure we clear the possibility that one callback can be updating two devices at same time...

Comment: I'm updating same key with same value for each device twin properties as I showed in the code. `twin.Properties.Desired["Pressure"] = "10.2";` This line is enough to update device property. Callback not updating devices. It just print something to screen. You can see from code.

Comment: @Zupermen new versions for Devices (1.22.0) and Devices.Client (1.27.0) [were released](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/releases). Can you check if the issue persists on those versions and if so open a bug under the [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues)? When you do so please reference this SO Thread and @ me 'asergaz'. Thanks!